# Using StructKeyExists in place of IsDefined

Tags: coldfusion, struct

For code enhancement purposes, we are going to convert all `isDefined()` calls to `structKeyExists()`. A couple of things that I need to know are:

How do we define a query in `structKeyExists()`? For instance:

```
<cfquery name="getname" datasource="dsn">select * from table</cfquery>

<cfif isDefined('getname') and getname.recordcount neq "">Do this</cfif>
```

Since there is no scope defined for `isDefined()`, what scope should we use for `structkeyExists()`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The default scope is variables, so `StructKeyExists(variables,"getname")` will perform your check for you.

However, unless there's missing logic in the example above, you don't need the isDefined/StructKeyExists check, because if you run a query, it'll always be defined, just with no rows present, so your second check on `getname.recordcount` should be sufficient.

Comment: Also, the logic of checking whether getnam.recordcount is empty won't work, as it'll be 0 for no rows, not an empty string

Comment: Also if you're running the query there's no need to check if it exists immediately after. Just check the recordCount

Comment: Thanks Guys, I never added the isDefined('queryName'). The reason i am doing is I was Getting production Error running ColdFusion 9, that QueryName is undefined. So i added That.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question but for posterity.

```
<cfquery name="getname" datasource="dsn">
    select * from table
</cfquery>

<cfif getname.recordcount>Do this</cfif>
```

The `cfif` `getname.recordcount` works as Boolean check.  If the result set brings nothing it fails...if it brings back a record than it satisfies the Boolean check.

To expand.  Lets say we are selecting a specific field like `id` and we want to provide output for either condition:

It would look like this:

```
<cfquery name="getname" datasource="dsn">
    select id from table
</cfquery>


<cfif getname.recordcount>
    <cfoutput query="getname">
    #id#<br>
    </cfoutput>
<cfelse>    
    No records found.    
</cfif>
```

Comment: getname.recordcount works as Boolean check, because either it will a number or 0. And 0 amounts to false in CF.

Comment: +1 on the further explination. :) Good for posterity.